# Fedora fails to find popular packages like apcalc or docker

Tags: fedora, yum, repository, dnf

I'm running Fedora 28 on my Acer Laptop for more than a week now. Since I usually use it at university, I decided to use the update server provided by the university, https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/.

At first this worked just fine but shortly after I changed the mirror, I found out that some packages that are listed in the fedora package list at https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/ were not available on my system. The error message is:

```
$ sudo dnf install docker
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:44 ago on Tue 29 May 2018 17:56:58 CEST.
No match for argument: docker
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

As soon as I revert my changes, I can install `docker` and `apcalc` without any issues.

Here is what I changed in `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo` and `fedora-updates.repo`:

```
# comment out the following line:
#metalink=...
# add this line instead:
baseurl=https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/fedora/linux/updates/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? If the issue cannot be fixed on my laptop, how can I debug/fix the issue on the server with the help of the server maintainer (who does not have a clue how Fedora works)?

Comment: You already told us how to fix the issue in your question.  It seems you need to select a repository that isn't missing the packages you want to install.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I have contacted the administrator of the halifax mirror already and he said that he does not have any clue why the packages are missing. If this is a problem with the server, can you still tell me how I can debug/fix the problem?

Comment: @msrd0 _You_ can't fix the server, but you could pick another mirror to see if it's a problem with the particular mirror that you're ordinarily using.

Comment: The `apcalc` program in debian is just called `calc` in Fedora. Try `sudo dnf install calc`. Since you say things work in the default configuration, maybe that's what you meant?

Comment: @mattdm I've used ArchLinux before where the package is called `calc`. Running `calc` on Fedora (with official repo list) suggests me to install `apcalc`, and running `sudo dnf install apcalc` worked just fine (I can't tell you why, it's obviously called `calc` in Fedora too).

Comment: @msrd0 That is super-weird. I actually maintain the Calc package in Fedora, and there's no apcalc anywhere. `sudo dnf install apcalc` definitely _doesn't_  work for me.

Comment: That said, I'm right now adding `Provides: apcalc` to the specfile so that in the future, it will work.

Comment: @mattdm Yes it is absolutely weird, and only my Laptop behaves like this, my other Fedora installation only knows the `calc` package

Comment: Are you sure there's not a third-party repo enabled?

Comment: @mattdm I did enable a repo for `spotify` and another one for `riot`, but even if one of them contained `apcalc` I'd expect that fedora suggests to install `calc` when I ask for a package containing the `calc` command and not some third-party repository

Comment: For me, if I don't have calc installed but type `calc`, it suggests `cal` as an alternative rather than suggesting an alternate package. The only thing I can think of is that one of the third-party repos has an `apcalc` package which is marked as `Provides: calc`.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a problem with your university's repository being an incomplete mirror.  Compare for example the packages (starting with the letter 'd' so as to seek your example case of `docker`) visible [here](https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/fedora/linux/updates/28/Everything/x86_64/Packages/d/) at your university, as opposed to [here](http://linux.mirrors.es.net/fedora/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/d/) at an official Fedora mirror (as found [here](https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-28&arch=x86_64)).  If you want to use your university's repository, you will need to convince its maintainer of the incompleteness of the mirror.

Comment: looks like my university is updating its mirror from the mirror of the _tu chemnitz_, which is just as incomplete as ours

Comment: In your example, you're comparing two different repositories. One is for updates repository, the other is for release repository. That's why one has packages that the other doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding your university mirror for Updates repository is correct.

Eventually, you are missing the "release repository". Can you please confirm if you have a "release repository" installed?

You should look at /etc/yum.repos.d for a configuration that has the base URL:

```
baseurl=http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
```